# what's the word for '' make something look smaller''?

Tags: word-request

The word I'm looking for is for calming  somebody down

Like this Example

> If you want to relax, you should make your problems look small(er) in
>   your mind.

- minify your problems
- minimize your problems
- belittle your problems

I don't think any of them are correct

what's the proper word for stating this sentence?

Comment: The best single word I can think of is [reduce](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reduce), but you might be better off not using a single word, but using an entire phrase to explain exactly what it is you want the reader to do.  (By the way, in common usage, *to belittle* really means something more like "to insult" than "to make small".)

Comment: @stangdon actually, the problem is big but you have to gain the skill to make it small in your mind . I think reduce means reduce the number of problems you have by doing sth but here you can't do anything about it. It's more of a mind skill.

Comment: It's a bit awkward because we're dealing with changing the subject's perceptions of the problems, not changing anything about the problems themselves, and any word will have to reflect that. "Deemphasize" might work, but I still don't think that quite gets at what you want.

Comment: I think "minimize" does actually work well. You might also consider "shrink".

Comment: You should think less of your problems.

Comment: @SovereignSun -  "Think less of" isn't bad, but I would rephrase it as "think less *about* your problems", because ["think less of" has the idiomatic meaning of "not respect as much" or "have a worse opinion of"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/think%20less%20of).

Comment: There is an idiom that is related, but not exactly what you're asking for: [Don't make mountains out of molehills.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_a_mountain_out_of_a_molehill)

Comment: I also vote for "minimize".  "Minify" would seem the perfect word except that it's a runty anytonym of **magnify** that the family hides in the attic and no one ever talks about or uses.

Answer (score 2):

"put in perspective", e.g. "If you step back and get a better perspective, you'll see the real size of your problems, which are probably smaller than they seem right now"

Comment: While this doesn't quite answer the question, it is a good way to express the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to relax you shouldn't focus on your problems.

or

you should palliate your issues.

The second one only kind of works.

Comment: Could you [edit] your post and explain your suggestions? What do they mean and how do they differ from the OP? Some dictionaries entries could be helpful too.